# What is the upper bound of $\operatorname{rank}(\lambda B - BA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

What is the upper bound of $\operatorname{rank}(\lambda B - BA)$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

My intuition is that the upper bound is $\operatorname{rank}(\begin{bmatrix} B \\ BA\end{bmatrix})$, but I do not know how to explain it.

Comment: $\lambda B-BA$ will give you a matrix of order $m \times n$ and we know rank $\leq $ min{m,n}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lambda B - BA = B(\lambda I_n - A)$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(B - BA) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(B),\operatorname{rank}(\lambda I_n - A)\}.
$$
So, your bound is correct in that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(B - BA) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{B\\ BA}.
$$